# How to declare function with multiple and limited options in Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I created function that can accept parameters in multiple ways like below.

To enable code working, VSC shows second parameter can be either boolean or number in one option.

```
export function sample(a: string, b: boolean | number): string {
  return '';
}

export function sample(a: string, b: boolean): string;

export function sample(a: string, b: number): string;
```

last ***sample*** function always gets compile error messing

*Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.'*

|

Also, when I try to import and use sample function in other file with VSC IDE,

```
sample() // shows three options 

1/3 sample(a: string, b: number | boolean): string
2/3 sample(a: string, b: boolean): string
3/3 sample(a: string, b: number): string
```

but I **want to make it show two options except the first one.**

How should I do?

|

FYI, I am working on Nest.js project though this might not be related to it

I try to search and find a way about declaring override function,
but keyword may not be correct.

Hope someone gives me a clue...

Comment: you can try function overloading https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading

Comment: can you edit your question and replace the image by the code itself? Images of code are not appreciated here.

Comment: @ruud Thnx for your advice. I edited as you advised.